# How does slicing work with double square brackets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I created a string variable `stro`.

How will the slicing `stro[7:][-6]` work on `stro`?

```
stro = "Python is fun"

print(stro[7:][-6])

# output: i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are slicing, then indexing:

```
stro = "Python is fun"
x = stro[7:]  # 'is fun'
y = x[-6]     # 'i'
```

Since strings are immutable, both `x` and `y` are new strings rather than a "view" of an object. Thus `stro[7:]` returns `'is fun'` and indexing the 6th last character returns `'i'`.

The syntax is similar to lists: see [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation).